Conditional query to find what games players are in & invited to
For each player, show their current games & invites in a "reasonably performant" query.
|   PLAYERS   |    |      GAMES     |  
|  ID  | Name |    | ID  |   Name   |
|------|------|    |-----|----------|
|  1   | Abby |    |  1  | Baccarat |
|  2   | Billy|    |  2  | BlackJack|
|  3   | Cary |    |  3  | Craps    |
|  4   | Dolly|    |  4  | Roulette |
|  5   | Eddy |

Players are invited to a game via a list. The list can be changed at any time so a player may be invited to a game and then dropped from the game in the following list:
|LIST|  |        INVITE             |
| ID |  | ID | LIST | PLAYER | GAME |
|----|  |----|------|--------|------|
| 1  |  |  1 |  1   |    1   |   2  |
| 2  |  |  2 |  1   |    2   |   2  |
| 3  |  |  3 |  1   |    3   |   2  |
| 4  |  |  4 |  1   |    4   |   2  |
| 5  |  |  5 |  1   |    5   |   2  |
| 6  |  |  6 |  2   |    1   |   2  |
| 7  |  |  7 |  2   |    2   |   2  |
| 8  |  |  8 |  2   |    3   |   2  |
| 9  |  |  9 |  2   |    4   |   2  |
        | 10 |  3   |    1   |   4  |
        | 11 |  3   |    2   |   4  |
        | 12 |  3   |    5   |   4  |
        | 13 |  4   |    4   |   1  |
        | 14 |  4   |    5   |   1  |
        | 15 |  5   |    1   |   4  |
        | 16 |  5   |    4   |   4  |
        | 17 |  5   |    5   |   4  |
        | 18 |  6   |    4   |   4  |
        | 19 |  6   |    5   |   4  |
        | 20 |  7   |    1   |   4  |
        | 21 |  7   |    2   |   4  |
        | 22 |  7   |    3   |   4  |
        | 23 |  7   |    4   |   4  |
        | 24 |  7   |    5   |   4  |
        | 25 |  8   |    1   |   3  |
        | 26 |  8   |    2   |   3  |
        | 27 |  8   |    3   |   3  |
        | 28 |  8   |    4   |   3  |

Before a round of a game is played, the list can be updated zero or more times. When the game starts, the round is marked as started and marked finished when complete.
|           ROUND    |        |
|  ID  | Game | List | State  |
|------|------|------|--------|
|  1   | 2    | 1    |FINISHED|
|  2   | 2    | 2    |FINISHED|
|  3   | 2    | 2    |STARTED |
|  4   | 4    | 3    |STARTED |
|  5   | 3    | 8    |STARTED |

A player's finished games:
SELECT * FROM GAMES G 
JOIN INVITE I ON I.GAME = G.ID
JOIN PLAYER P ON P.ID   = I.PLAYER
JOIN ROUND  R ON G.ID   = R.GAME
WHERE R.STATE = 'FINISHED'

but I'm struggling the conditional query for the current games and invites. I think the current games query is:
SELECT * FROM GAMES G 
JOIN INVITE I ON I.GAME = G.ID
JOIN PLAYER P ON P.ID   = I.PLAYER
JOIN ROUND  R ON G.ID   = R.GAME
WHERE R.STATE = 'STARTED'

and I think the invite portion is:
SELECT * FROM GAMES G 
JOIN INVITE I ON I.GAME = G.ID
JOIN PLAYER P ON P.ID   = I.PLAYER
WHERE I.LIST            = (
  SELECT MAX(LL.ID) 
  FROM LIST LL 
  WHERE         LL.GAME = G.ID
)

but I'm stumped on combining these and whether this is a "reasonably performant" solution.
Desired Results
Lists do the following:

everyone sees BlackJack.
removes Eddy and Dolly from BlackJack
adds Roulette to Abby, Billy and Eddy
adds Baccarat to Dolly and Eddy
removes Billy from Baccarat and adds Dolly
removes Abby from Baccarat
removes Dolly and Eddy from Baccarat and adds Abby, Billy, and Cary
adds Billy, Cary, and Dolly to Craps

Rounds do the following:

started and finished BlackJack with list #1
started and finished BlackJack with List #2
started BlackJack with list #2
started Roulette with list #3
started Craps with list #8

As each participant signs-in, they see a list of games that they're invited to and possibly started; while the game is playing they can see the game. Once the game is finished, they can only see the game if they're (re-)invited in the most recent list. A separate query is used to see finished games each player was in. Some lists are never applied to a round.
Given a player ID, show the list of current games and invited games. For example, for Abby once list #1 is created, Abby sees BlackJack; when round 1 starts Abby sees BlackJack; when list 2 is created Abby continues to see BlackJack

Please show us the results you are hoping to achieve from your query.

Of course, Dale -- I've now added a bit more description in the "desired results" section (as well as corrected a few data errors in the tables).

In addition to a description, we also need to see your actual desired results for the provided sample data, i.e. show the resultset you expect

While I find it a bit hard to follow, I can already say this much: The invite table looks bad, and I suppose it is violating database normalization rules.
It seems that each list refers to exactly one game. So the game ID should be an attribute in the list table, not in the invite table and not in the rounds table.
CREATE TABLE player (
  id_player SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name      VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE game (
  id_game SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE list (
  id_list SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_game INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES game
);

CREATE TABLE invite (
  id_invite SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_list   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES list,
  id_player INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES player
);

CREATE TABLE round (
  id_round SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_list  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES list,
  status   VARCHAR(10)
);

Now, if I understand correcty, the list is to be interpreted as a per game history. So for every game we look at its most current list to know which players are currently invited in that game.
In your example

the most recent list for game 1 is list 4
the most recent list for game 2 is list 2
the most recent list for game 3 is list 8.
the most recent list for game 4 is list 7

The other lists are just history that we don't have to look at.
Now you want to show all rounds for all games a player is still invited to. Something like
WITH
  latest_lists AS
  (
    SELECT id_game, MAX(id_list) AS last_id_list
    FROM list
    GROUP BY id_game
  )
SELECT p.name, r.id_round, g.name, r.status
FROM round r
JOIN latest_lists ll ON ll.last_id_list = r.id_list
JOIN game g ON g.id_game = ll.id_game
JOIN invite i ON i.id_list = ll.last_id_list
JOIN player p ON p.id_player = i.id_player
ORDER BY p.name, r.id_round;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/fdcFvPuD

Indeed, Thorsten, "the game ID should be an attribute in the list table"; unfortunately, I can't change this in the near term.

Your sample was very helpful, Thorsten -- thank you. I had hope to solve this query problem before correcting the invite table problems but it feels like it needs to be solved first.

Well, until you get the database fixed, you could work with a view to get a list with a game column. E.g., by starting a query with with better_list as (select l.id, max(i.game) as game from list l join invite i on i.list = l.id group by l.id), and then just ignore the game column in invite and round.
